# Table is not showing in reactjs useTable hook when data is being accessed from backend in Spring boot via axios

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, react-hooks

Sometimes when I save table which has two products in backend (it's a product table display on frontend) shows but not everytime when I call the component as expected.

The component is called through routing in App.js and through /productshow url. In console though fetched data.

I have tried simple h1 tag in place of table and it works fine. Some error is definitely occuring in rendering the table

```
   const DisplayProduct = () => {

   toast.success("in Display");

   const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
   const getAllProductsFromServer = () => {
       axios.get(`${base_url}/productshow`).then(
           (response) => {
               console.log(response);
               setProduct(response.data);
               console.log("Done");
           },
           (error) => {
               console.log(error);

           }
       );
   };


   useEffect(() => {
       getAllProductsFromServer();
   }, []);

   const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
   const data = useMemo(() => product, [])

   const TableInstance = useTable(
       {
           columns,
           data,
       }
   )
   const {
       getTableProps,
       getTableBodyProps,
       headerGroups,
       rows,
       prepareRow,
   } = TableInstance

   return (
       <table {...getTableProps()}>
           <thead>
               {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => {
                   <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                       {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                           <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                               {column.render('Header')}
                           </th>
                       ))}
                   </tr>
               })}

           </thead>
           <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
               {rows.map((row) => {
                   prepareRow(row)
                   return (

                       <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                           {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                               return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                           })}

                       </tr>
                   )

               })}

           </tbody>
       </table>
   )


};

export default DisplayProduct;
```